# How can I get all entities with a certain name from a JSON Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I got some json that has objects nested within objects. I need to extract every entity that has the name "body". is there a way to do this without writing a long algorithm?

http://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/22rx5c.json

Comment: Would help if you added the code you've already tried to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to recursively loop through each node and its children and check their key name. There are libraries that can help you with this. Alternatively you could use [xpath for JSON](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/).

Answer (score 1):

You can try so:

```
$.getJSON('http://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/22rx5c.json', function(json){
    result = [];
    recurse('body', json);
    console.log(result);
});

function recurse(toFind, json){
    for( var key in json ){
        if( typeof json[key] == 'object' ){
            recurse( toFind, json[key] );
        }
        if( key == toFind ){
           result[result.length] = json[key]; 
        }
    }
};
```

here you can find the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z9g2G/)